# Cannot install Axis2 -Plugin on Eclipse Kepler or Mar

Tags: eclipse, apache-axis

I am not able to install Axis2 in Eclipse. I followed the steps outlined below

> 1. Downloaded the 2 plugins from https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/index.html
>
>    1. service archive generator (org.apache.axis2.eclipse.service.plugin_1.6.3)
>    2. Axis2 code generator (org.apache.axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin_1.6.3)
> 2. Unzipped and move the 2 jar files into the drop ins folder.
> 3. Pointed the Axis2 run time location under Windows > Preferences > Web Services > Axis2 Preferences to C:\axis2-1.6.3. This is where I
>      installed downloaded the standalone version from here -
>      http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.cgi

I also restarted eclipse. I do not see the **Axis2** wizard in `File > New > Other`.

I am not sure what step I am missing. Is there a bug on the 1.6.3 version that might be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything in the Error Log view?

Comment: I see this - user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\myuser'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in the last Axis2 release:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-5714

Comment: Thanks Andreas, Can you provide gudance on what needs to be downloaded ?

Comment: At the end of the bug report, there is a link to the latest snapshot builds. Select the Eclipse plugin you want to install and download the ZIP file.